# Ошибки при работе с удаленным репозиторием git

Tags: linux, git

При попытке из CentOS выгрузить git репозиторий командой `git push origin` возникает ошибка:

> sh: 1: git-receive-pack: not found
>   fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Тоже самое вполне себе работает из windows систем, т.е. на удаленной стороне все в порядке. Пути до `git-receive-pack` и `git-upload-pack` для пользователя, выполняющего выгрузку, прописаны.

Как побороть?

Comment: `git config --global user.name "YourGitName"`

`git config --global user.email "YourGit@e.mail"`

Заданы?

Comment: Покажите git remote -v в обеих системах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в CentOS авторизация производилась по паролю, а из windows систем по ключу.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/445335)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, автор вопроса нашел причину проблемы, ее нужно было указать в комментарии?